# jQuery :not() issue

Tags: jquery, selector

jQuery 1.4:

```
$('#menu li:last:not(.ignore)').addClass('last');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li class="ignore">item3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

.. `last` class is not applied to `item 2`. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the order of `:last` and `:not()`:

```
$('#menu li:not(.ignore):last')
```

Comment: Ah! I'd dismissed that thought because :last:not worked earlier, but not in jquery 1.4 I guess. Thanks anyway!! :)

Comment: @Nimbuz: The selectors `:not(…):last` and `:last:not(…)` have different semantics. The former will first exclude all elements that do not match the `:not(…)` expression and then get the last element of them. The latter will first get the last element and then exclude it if it does not match the `:not(…)` condition.

Answer (score 2):

The way your expression works is this:

- Find the element with ID "menu";
- Find all descendant list items of that element;
- Limit the results to the very last element in that set;
- Filter out elements (which is only one element by this point, the last one) that don't have a class of "ignore".

The last element has a class of ignore so it is filtered out. That's why it doesn't work. Reverse the order:

```
$("#menu li:not(.ignore):last").addClass("last");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems more logical to me at least to say *'get me the list item before the first occurence of .ignore'*:

```
// tested
$("#menu li.ignore:first").prev("li").addClass('last');
```